# accidently deleted linux image and header files, grub not showing up already

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, 20.04, kernel

I deleted my linux header and image files by command as below :

`sudo apt remove linux-image-5.8.0-50-generic linux-headers-5.8.0-50-generic`

also `uname -r` result is `5.8.0-50-generic`

I could have changed the kernal in grub, but its a problem already that its menu not opening up at startup on holding **shift** or **Esc** ! Did changes as per the suggestions on this platform and other but no help!

Now what's happening is that, OS is opening up but the display resolution is 640x480 and internet can't be connected! What I did is I have a bootable pendrive and using live image I installed those same files and updated grub but nothing changed!

I'm in need of urgent help! I was trying to go to previous kernal since after the update it was flickering my screen too much and I was not able to do any work!

Comment: I think you are looking at a fresh install.

Comment: @David Can this be done without disturbing the settings? Otherwise it will be too much time and data consuming!

Comment: No one can tell you there will be no data loss. If you do install the exact same version and do not have any PPA there is a chance but that is remote. You need to prepare a full data back up first.